# Codenameone: How to prevent the android hardware-back-button to exit the app?

Tags: android, hardware, codenameone, back-button

When I run my Codenameone-App on an android-device, pressing the hardware-back-button stops/exits my app. I added a back-Command to the form - but this does not work. The hardware-back-button works as expected, when I call a second form from the first form and press the hardware-back-button there (the second form closes and the first is shown).

How can I prevent, that the App exits when the hardware-back-button is pressed on the first form?

Answer (score 2):

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // nothing to code
    }
```

You have to override onBackPressed method and keep it empty , then your app won't get exit when you press back button from the first screen

Answer (score 2):

Call `form.setBackCommand(new Command(""));` to disable the default minimize behavior on the `Form`.

Comment: Hmm - I'm sorry - but adding an empty Command() as backCommand to the form does not prevent the App to be stopped when the hardware-back-button is pressed. Is there anything else I could try? Two other developer wrote, that I should override onBackPressed() - but I can't find a class where I can overwrite this method.

Comment: You need to do this on the right form instance, are you using the old gui builder or something else. Those other guys are talking about native Android which isn't applicable here.

Comment: I create the main form in the start-class (the one with the start() and init() method) as an instance-variable.  There are also other forms, which are called/opened from the main-form. The other forms have back-commands, which worked correct with the android hardware-back-button (this means the app is not exited - but the main form is opened again with showBack()). The older GUI-Builder is only used for styling purpose.

Comment: When they do "back" do they create a new form instance or return to the previous instance?

Comment: They return to the previous instance with showBack()

Comment: Let's try a different direction. In the theme go the constants tab and add `minimizeOnBackBool` check it then uncheck it so it is set to false and save.

Comment: Great - this worked :-)   Is it possible to set a user-defined action when the hardware-back-button is pressed - for example with a not-empty back-command in the form?

Comment: It should be possible to use setBackCommand with a Command that overrides action performed

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `onBackPressed()` to handle the back button click :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Leaving it as such, would make your app non responsive to back button. If I understood the question correctly, that's what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Which class in Codename one has a method onBackPressed() which could be overridden?

Comment: I did not get your comment properly, would be better if you can explain it more!

Comment: Override a method means, that there is a class which already has such a method. But I cannot find a class which already has a method called onBackPressed().

Comment: I'm sorry - but I don't understand...  I don't use any Activity class. Do we talk about a Codenameone standard-App?